# overloading operator << c++, I am trying to cout the element of class

Tags: c++

I am writing this code

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, Box& B){
    return B.l +" "+B.b +" "+B.h +endl;
};
```

The error I get is

```
Solution.cpp:40:46: error: ‘std::ostream& Box::operator<<(std::ostream&, Box&)’ must have exactly one argument ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, Box& B){ ^
```

can someone explain what's wrong? I dont understand.

thanks for your help :)

Comment: Must be `return  out <<  B.l << " " << B.b << " " << B.h  << endl;`

Comment: You may need to show the definitiion of `Box`.

Comment: @VictorGubin it give methis error **Solution.cpp:40:46: error: ‘std::ostream& Box::operator<<(std::ostream&, Box&)’ must have exactly one argument ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, Box& B){ ^ –** can you please explain?

Comment: @Sofirul Danatriya you are re-defining `<<` operator for std::ostream class, not for `B`. Please read the streams section of [The C++ Programming Language 38.4.2](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html)

Comment: @SofirulDanatriya If you think this is related to operator overloading, please also post the definition of the class `Box`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you mean the following

```
std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream& out, const Box& B) {
    return out << B.l << " " << B.b << " " << B.h;
}
```

provided that all used in the operator data members are public data members of the class `Box`. The operator shall be declared and defined outside the class definition.

If one of the used data members is a private data member of the class then the function should be a friend function of the class and shall be declared (and may be defined) in the class definition. For example

```
class Box
{
    //...
    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream& out, const Box& B) {
        return out << B.l << " " << B.b << " " << B.h;
    }
    //...
};
```

Pay attention to that it is better to remove in the return statement the operand `std::endl`. In this case 1) the operator will be more flexible because you can output additional information in the same line and 2) this statement

```
std::cout << box;
```

will not confuse readers of the code because they will not see the operand `std::endl`.

Without this operand in the operator definition in the caller of the operator you can write

```
std::cout << box << std::endl;
```

and this statement more clear expresses the intention of the programmer.

Answer (score 2):

It should probably be:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Box const& B){
    out << B.l << " " << B.b << " " << B.h << std::endl;
    return out;
};
```

Full code should look like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Box {
    int l;
    int b;
    int h;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Box const& B);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Box const& B){
    out << B.l << " " << B.b << " " << B.h << std::endl;
    return out;
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z: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%2ByS1obXGd3Fn%2Btw8wWi6QS/08woQGtSI3CxnSHBYDBEChUEYPHh2GQKBA0IfjxVgIihqQqMeCM5lxAHE28w5rGkAJ7Z%2BukC8jC0AgAHlaFYX8N1ILAo1Edh32gvAFgKAA3TBlygzBjnyYMBjnO5lAQ1g8AcAViG/PQsD/BtQSMd9OhoegmDYDgeH4QRhFEFA5DkIQSOXSBOlRJIMIAWkhaYWQkcsZE4f8EnyJJNG0WpslIcxSiiGJgm8Xw6FUnTQj8TTyliXJEkKRoDPqPICjoIp0hM1ozIaYprKqYonO0zhOgUKs%2Bi4TNs1zfMEIXY4AA5EVExFuAmYBkGQCZEU1IYJggXBCBIWscgmPRLxPHK4zLWQZAbejOgQRYsBcWNSHbTg1lXSdp1IOjXFXWdi2zJcVzXeit13CAkDJDxg3ISgLyPE8zHwTFBEYxgWHgtiAHcBQ8aigpzGcwuzYZOAmVbCCdSLoti%2BLEuS1Lyo3FtSCq5gasoNsuCaoRs1a9rOr2xdFD69dm1e7gzm7bg4lcHshmh2Khgij7%2BiGXaoIXW6gYRyRkbnVH%2Bruzo0OIHwNG4IA%3D%3D%3D)

Comment: @VictorGubin I didn't get what you mean. Can you please explain?

Comment: still giving me this error **Solution.cpp:40:46: error: ‘std::ostream& Box::operator<<(std::ostream&, Box&)’ must have exactly one argument
     ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, Box& B){
                                              ^**

Comment: @SofirulDanatriya note that this operator overload should be defined outside of the class definition

Comment: @SofirulDanatriya you have memebr operator but you declared stand-alone.  That kind of operator cannot be memeber.

Answer (score 0):

To output a type T to `std::ostream`, you have to declare standalone operator, which returns reference to that stream

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const T& B)
{
    out << B.l << " " << B.b << " " << B.h << '\n';
    return out;
}
```

This operation cannot be member operator because member operator use their class as first argument, therefore it might be necessary declare it as a friend of class T.

Avoid using `endl` in such operators if not extremely necessary, that manipulator calls `out.flush()`. If you want new line added, use  new-line character.